# executeScript doesn't work after navigating inside inAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I'm trying to inject code into a website that was opened via InAppBrowser with:

```
var inappbrowser = window.open('http://example.com', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
```

For that, I'm using (not exactly in this structure, but to the same effect):

```
var loop;
inappbrowser.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
    console.log('page finished loading - ' + JSON.stringify(event));
    clearInterval(loop);
    loop = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('checking for request');
        inappbrowser.executeScript({
            code: '1+2'
        }, function(result) {
            console.log('received: ' + result);
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

It works fine with the initial page, but once I navigate to another page from inside InAppBrowser, no script is executed. The event works, the loop works, but `'received: [3]'` doesn't get logged at all anymore.

Plugins currently installed are:

- InAppBrowser
- Console
- BarcodeScanner

InAppBrowser and BarcodeScanner were both installed directly from their Github repositories.

- Cordova version: 3.3 (tried 3.4 as well, with the same result)
- Xcode: 5.0.2
- iOS Target Version: 7

I always use `cordova prepare` and then run with Xdebug directly on an iPad Air. I have also tried `cordova build ios`.

I've also noticed that the script gets later executed **while** navigating to another page.
It also does **not** run while scrolling on the initial page.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Also, does this happen with everyone else?

Thanks a lot in advance! I've researched, started from scratch in brand new cordova projects, and basically spent the whole day on this strange occurrence...

Comment: P.S. access origin is currently set to *, so no whitelist issues should be applicable.

Comment: P.S.2. based on http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-23/cross-window-communication-with-cordova's-inappbrowser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems the problem was the loop... it has to be cleared at loadstart.

So the following solved it:

```
self.inappbrowser.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {

    trace('loading page - ' + JSON.stringify(event));

    clearInterval(loop);
});
```

Hope this helps someone else as well!